# Can continuity be characterized by nets?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, nets

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces  (not necessarily assumed to be  Hausdorff or to have any additional property) and let $f:X\to Y$ be a given function.  Is it true that $f$ is continuous iff
for every $x\in  X$, and every net $\{x_i\}_i$ converging to $x$, one has that
$f(x_i)\to f(x)$.

---

PS: I have searched for this specific question in MSE and, although I found several posts discussing it ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626212/continuity-in-terms-of-nets),
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086004/continuity-and-convergent-nets), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360419/f-brings-convergent-nets-to-convergent-nets-is-it-continuous)) with varying degress of objectivity, and using various additional hypothesis (Hausdorff,
completely regular, first countable) I do not believe it can be found in the exact terms above.

I therefore thought it would be nice to register it here.

I am also providing an answer which I hope  is similar to the one in [The Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK) $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proof of the "only if" part is well known, so let us prove the "if" part.

Assuming by contradiction that $f$ is discontinuous at a point $x$ in $X$, we will build a net $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ converging
to $x$, such that $\{f(x_i)\}_{i\in I}$ does not converge  to $f(x)$.  The set of indices for our net will be the set $N_x$
formed by  all neighborhoods of
$x$, and viewed as a directed set with order given by reverse inclusion,  namely,
$$
  U\geq V \Leftrightarrow   U\subseteq  V.
  $$

Since $f$ is discontinuous at $x$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $f(x)$ such that $f(V)\not\subseteq U$, for all
$V\in N_x$. Therefore,   for any such $V$ we may  choose some $x_V\in V$ such that $f(x_V)\not\in U$.

It is then evident that the net $\{x_V\}_{V\in  N_x}$ converges to $x$, while $\{f(x_V)\}_{V\in  N_x}$ does not converge to $f(x)$.

---

PS:  The same argument above shows that $f$ is continuous **at a given point** $x_0$,
if and only  if,  for every net $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$,  converging to $x_0$,  one has that
$\{f(x_i)\}_{i\in I}$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

Comment: I think everyone that knows what a net is knows this result.

Comment: @QuantumSpace, I agree but I think there is a lot of people unsure of the precise hypotheses (namely none) needed to prove it.  Just check out the posts I refered to above to see what I mean.

Comment: A bit strange I would say, but yes that makes your post useful for the community! I'd say keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose first that $f$ is continuous. Let $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ converge to $x$. Let $V \subset Y$ be open containing $f(x)$. Then
$$x \in f^{-1}(V)$$
which is open by continuity of $f$, thus there exists some $\alpha_0 \in A$ such that
$$x_\alpha \in f^{-1}(V)$$
for all $\alpha \ge \alpha_0$. Then we have
$$f(x_\alpha) \in V$$
forcing $f(x_\alpha) \rightarrow f(x)$.

Conversely, suppose that if $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ converges to $x$, then $(f(x_\alpha))_{\alpha \in A}$ converges to $f(x)$. And assume $f$ is discontinuous at $x$. I.e., there exists some open set $V \subset Y$ containing $f(x)$ such that
$$x \in (f^{-1}(V))^\circ = \overline{f^{-1}(V^c)}.$$
Then one can conclude that there exists a net $(x_\alpha)$ such that for all $\alpha \geq \alpha_0$ one has
$$x_\alpha \in f^{-1}(V^c).$$
Then for all $\alpha \geq \alpha_0$ one has that since $f(x) \in V$ that
$$f(x_\alpha) \in V.$$
This is a contradiction since $f(x_\alpha) \in V^c$ thus $f$ is continuous.