# show if convergent nets get mapped to convergent nets then $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, continuity, nets

Forgive me if this is a repeat post but it didn't have the solution I was looking for which is one by contradiction.

For the following proof, $\mathcal{O}(x)$ is the set of open neighborhoods of $x$.

So I suppose that if $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ converges to $x$, then $(f(x_\alpha))_{\alpha \in A}$ converges to $f(x)$. And assume $f$ is discontinuous. Then there exists $x \in X$ such that $V$ is an open neigborhood for $f(x)$ but $f^{-1}(V)$ is not an open neighborhood of $x$. Thus setting $A=$ the set of neighborhoods of some $y \in X$ ordered by reverse inclusion ($A \geq B \Rightarrow A \subseteq B$) we can construct a net $(y_U)_{U \in \mathcal{O}(y)}$ such that
$$y_U \not\in f^{-1}(V)$$
which implies
$$f(y_U) \not\in V.$$
For all $U_O \leq U$ some $U_0 \in \mathcal{O}(y)$.
Choose any neighborhood of $y$, say $W$. Then for $T \geq W$, $T,W \in \mathcal{O}(y)$, one has that
$$y_T \in W.$$
It follows then that there exists some $U_0$ such that whenever $U_0 \leq U$, $(y_U)_{U \in \mathcal{O}(y)}$ converges to $y$ thus $(f(y_U))_{U \in \mathcal{O}(y)}$ converges to $f(x)$ which implies
$$f(y_U) \in V$$
a contradiction.

Basically, was the trick to let my directed indexing set be the set of open neighborhoods of a given point in the net? ordered by reverse inclusion.

Comment: This post needs some more editing before it can be answered I think. Are all your $y$s supposed to be $x$s?

Comment: The ys are the net I constructed from discontinuity of $f$ @StevenClontz

Comment: Some other posts on this site related to this question: [$f$ is continuous if and only if, $f(x_d) \to f(x)$ where $(x_d)_{d \in D}$ is a net such that $x_d \to x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4348575) and [Can continuity be characterized by nets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3958660)

Comment: If your main goal is to get some suggestions about your proofs, I think you should use that tag ([tag:solution-verification]).

Comment: @MartinSleziak so was I correct? I have added the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is discontinuous. That is, there exists an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \in V$ for some open $V \subset Y$ but

$$x \in (f^{-1}(V)^\circ)^c$$

This implies $x \in \overline{f^{-1}(V^c)}$, then there is a net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ inside of $f^{-1}(V^c)$ converging to $x$. Then $(f(x_\alpha))$ converges to $f(x)$ which means $f(x_\alpha) \in V$ for all $\alpha$ but this is a contradiction as $f(x_\alpha) \in V^c$ and the proof is done.